# Inherting the label class: Click event not appearing

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to make a custom label for myself to carry more properties, since I needed more than on label `tag`. I geenrated a new class inherting the Label class as follows:

```
public class BigLabel : Label
    {
        private int t;
        private string h;
        public int ST
        {
            get
            {
                return t;
            }
            set
            {
                t = value;
            }
        }
        public string HyperLink
        {
            get
            {
                return h;
            }
            set
            {
                h = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I use this in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, BigLabel lb = new BigLabel(); 
`lb.Click` event is not appearing here after I inherited the Label class. Is something wrong?

Comment: Since you mentioned XAML, i believe your handling WPF stuffs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Label` class does not have a `Click` event. Anyway here's how you could add one:

```
public static RoutedEvent ClickEvent;         

static BigLabel()    
{    
    ClickEvent = ButtonBase.ClickEvent.AddOwner(typeof(BigLabel));    
}    

public event RoutedEventHandler Click    
{    
    add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }    
    remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }    
}
```

And you'll have to raise the event on `MouseUp`:

```
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ClickEvent, this));
```

Comment: Can I add a click event in that case?